# Not able to get the correct relationship count in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

We are trying to build an application in Laravel 8 where we need to fetch some data through complex queries. Let me explain my model structure to you:

I have a `Brand` model, which is related to multiple `Group` and `SubGroup` model with many-to-many relation. Each brand is associated with multiple `Project` with respect to `Group` and `SubGroup` model.

So my Brand model looks like:

```
public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class, 'brand_group', 'brand_id', 'group_id');
}

public function subgroup()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(SubGroup::class, 'brand_subgroup', 'brand_id', 'sub_group_id');
}

public function projects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class, 'project_associate_brand', 'brand_id', 'project_id');
}
```

I've a pivot table `project_associated_brand` which has `project_id`, `group_id`, `sub_group_id`, `brand_id`
Considering the pivot table I've defined the relationship in `Project`, `Group` and `SubGroup`:

`Project` model:

```
public function brand()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Brand::class, 'project_associate_brand', 'project_id', 'brand_id');
}

public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class, 'project_associate_brand', 'project_id', 'group_id');
}

public function subgroup()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(SubGroup::class, 'project_associate_brand', 'project_id', 'sub_group_id');
}
```

`Group` model:

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class, 'project_associate_brand', 'group_id', 'project_id');
}

public function brand()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Brand::class,'brand_group',
        'group_id', 'brand_id')->withTimestamps();;
}
```

`SubGroup` model:

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class, 'project_associate_brand', 'sub_group_id', 'project_id');
}

public function brand()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Brand::class,'brand_subgroup',
        'sub_group_id', 'brand_id')->withTimestamps();;
}
```

I want to extract `Project` count from `SubGroup` with respect to each `Brand`

```
return SubGroup::with(['group', 'brand.projects' => function($q) {
            $q->where('projects.status','saved');
        }])->get();
```

Currently I'm getting the output:

```
[ {sub_group_name: 'abc subgroup', brands: [ {brand_name: 'lddf', project_count: 10}, {brand_name: 'uoweyr', project_count: 21}]} ]
```

Currently I'm getting all the projects count related to brands. I need to filter them too with respective `SubGroup` models also, what I expect the output:

```
[ {sub_group_name: 'abc subgroup', brands: [ {brand_name: 'lddf', project_count: 8}, {brand_name: 'uoweyr', project_count: 16}]} ]
```

Here `project_count` is filtered as per the `Brand` and `SubGroup`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the where callback function to both the relation and the parent query:

```
$fn = function($q) {
    $q->where('projects.status','saved');
};
SubGroup::with(['group', 'brand.projects' => $fn])->whereHas('brand.projects', $fn)->get();
```

Comment: the projects are not getting filtered with respect to `subgroup`

Answer (score 0):

you can use where Has call back function , this method allow you to write a  query as Project model

read more from here :
[1]: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships